# How to publish an audio stream from a client with FluorineFx?

Tags: c#, apache-flex, streaming, rtmp, fluorinefx

I can't figure out how to publish an audio stream from a client to the server using FluorineFx on the client. We want to stream recorded audio data from the client to the stream via the already established NetConnection. There is a NetStream class in FluorineFx but it has no publish method. The NetStream class in FluorineFx only has the play method. But as far as I understand this plays a stream from the server on the client.

Is publish not implemented in FluorineFx or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to be implemented.

Comment: Now, Is it possible to publish in fluorinefx? `ns.publish(publishName.text,"record");`

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/

See **Publishing streams and subscribing to streams** under **Real-time Messaging**.

Comment: Thanks but I already read that article. The proplem is: There are no attachAudio or publish methods in the NetStream class in FluorineFx. I think they talk about the Flex side in that article.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also look into the codes of fluorinefx. It is strange why the publish is not implemented in the codes although the doc mentioned it.

Actually, in its PlayEngine.cs, there is a similar implementation PullAndPush() which can pull data from a FLV file and push it to the remote.

So, I tried some similar codes in Netstream class, it can almost work and can push the stream to the *rtmplite* server and can be played by the test web in *rtmplite*.

```
public void Publish(params object[] arguments)
        {
            ValidationUtils.ArgumentConditionTrue(arguments != null && arguments.Length > 0, "arguments", "At least the name of a file must be specified");
            ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNullOrEmptyOrWhitespace(arguments[0] as string, "name");
            _name = arguments[0] as string;


            INetConnectionClient client = _connection.NetConnectionClient;
            RtmpConnection connection = _connection.NetConnectionClient.Connection as RtmpConnection;
            IPendingServiceCallback callback = new CreateStreamCallBack(this, connection, new PublishCallBack(this,_connection, _name));
            client.Call("createStream", callback);
        }

        public void AttachFile(string filepath)
        {

            FileProvider fileProvider = new FileProvider(this.Scope, new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath));
            _pullPushPipe.Subscribe(fileProvider, null);
            PullAndPush();
        }

        public void PullAndPush()
        {

            while(true)
            {
                var msg = _pullPushPipe.PullMessage();
                if (msg == null)
                {
                    // No more packets to send
                    Stop();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (msg is RtmpMessage)
                    {
                        RtmpMessage rtmpMessage = (RtmpMessage)msg;
                        IRtmpEvent body = rtmpMessage.body;
                     //   SendMessage(rtmpMessage);
                        // Adjust timestamp when playing lists
                        //  EnsurePullAndPushRunning();
                        _pullPushPipe.PushMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class PublishCallBack : IPendingServiceCallback
        {
            NetConnection _connection;
            NetStream _stream;
            string _name;
            string _mode;

            public PublishCallBack(NetStream stream, NetConnection connection, string name, string mode = "live")
            {
                _connection = connection;
                _name = name;
                _mode = mode;
                _stream = stream;
            }

            public void ResultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call)
            {
                if ("createStream".Equals(call.ServiceMethodName))
                {
                    RtmpConnection connection = _connection.NetConnectionClient.Connection as RtmpConnection;
                    object[] args = new object[2] {_name, _mode};
                    PendingCall pendingCall = new PendingCall("publish", args);
                    pendingCall.RegisterCallback(new PublishResultCallBack());
                    connection.Invoke(pendingCall, (byte)connection.GetChannelForStreamId(_stream.StreamId));
                }
            }
        }
```